# How to look for unknown character by richTextBox.find in c#?

Tags: c#, find, richtextbox

There is a richTextBox on a windows form in C#. I'm looking for a special string by find method.
For example I'm looking for 'cat' string in the text. As you know there could be a lot of string depends on cat like: cat or cats or cat's or Cat or CAT or cat. or cat, or cat: or cat\n or even something like category or catalyst or Catia and  other types. How can I look for just cat as an animal like cat, or cat: or cat. or cat or cat's or cats and etc. Is there any character that I can use instead? something like ' cat?' or ' cat*' to look for all of characters.

This is the method I'm using:

```
private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Checked)
        {
            CheckedNodes.Add(e.Node);
        }
        else
        {
            CheckedNodes.Remove(e.Node);
        }



        richTextBox1.SelectAll();
        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
        richTextBox1.DeselectAll();

        for (int counter = 0; counter < CheckedNodes.Count; counter++)
        {
            int location = 0;

            while (location != -1)
            {
                location = FindMyText(" " + CheckedNodes[counter].Text + "", location + 1, richTextBox1.TextLength);


                if (location != -1)
                {
                    FindMyText(CheckedNodes[counter].Text, location + 1, richTextBox1.TextLength);
                    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = CheckedNodes[counter].ForeColor;
                }
            }
        }

        richTextBox1.DeselectAll();

    }


    public int FindMyText(string searchText, int searchStart, int searchEnd)
    {
        // Initialize the return value to false by default. 
        int returnValue = -1;

        // Ensure that a search string and a valid starting point are specified. 
        if (searchText.Length > 0 && searchStart >= 0)
        {
            // Ensure that a valid ending value is provided. 
            if (searchEnd > searchStart || searchEnd == -1)
            {
                // Obtain the location of the search string in richTextBox1. 
                int indexToText = richTextBox1.Find(searchText, searchStart, searchEnd, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
                // Determine whether the text was found in richTextBox1. 
                if (indexToText >= 0)
                {
                    // Return the index to the specified search text.
                    returnValue = indexToText;
                }
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find an Enhanced Rich text box control, the only problem that its in VB.net,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32793/RichTextBox-Control-with-Find-functionality

but it solves your problem.